# Adding a Healthbar to enemies PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Python and recently started working with PyGame. I read a tutorial online that did step-by-step code to a 2D game. I took that code and modified it to add new content. I added a health bar to enemies to make the game more challenging but whenever there is more than one enemy on screen, all the enemies health decrease when I only shoot one and then resets as soon as one enemy is removed from the screen. I know I probably need to create a Class, but I was wondering if I can't just add the enemies to a list and then decrease each enemy's health individually?

EDIT:
To clear up confusion:
If I shoot at an enemy, only that enemy's health value should decrease and not all the enemies' health value as is currently happening. I want a separate health value for each enemy on the screen, which should be removed as soon as that specific enemy's health drops to zero or below.

## Here is the code for the Health bar:

```
    6.3.2 - Check for collisions
    index1=0

    for bullet in arrows:
        bullrect=pygame.Rect(arrow.get_rect())
        bullrect.left=bullet[1]
        bullrect.top=bullet[2]
        if badrect.colliderect(bullrect):
            weapon_damage = random.randint(8,20)
            enemy.play()
            acc[0]+=1
            for badguy in badguys:
                badguy_health -= weapon_damage



            if badguy_health <= 0:
                for shot in badguys:
                    arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(badguydead, 360-projectile[0]*57.29)
                    screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
                    for badguy in badguys:
                        if badguy_health < 65 and badguy_health > 0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            badguy_health = 65
                badguys.pop(index)
                rand_enemy= random.choice(enemyArray)
            else:
                screen.blit(explosion, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
            arrows.pop(index1)
        index1+=1

    # 6.3.3 - Next bad guy
    index+=1

for badguy in badguys:
    screen.blit(enemy_healthbar, (badguy[0], badguy[1]))
    for health2 in range(badguy_health):
        screen.blit(enemy_health_block, (badguy[0]+health2,badguy[1]))
    screen.blit(rand_enemy, badguy)
```

## How I draw the enemies:

```
 if badtimer==0:
            random_Y_position = random.randint(50,430)
            badguys.append([800, random_Y_position])
            badtimer=100-(badtimer1*2)

            if badtimer1>=35:
                badtimer1=35
            else:
                badtimer1+=5

        index=0
        for badguy in badguys:
            if badguy[0]<-64:
                badguys.pop(index)
            badguy[0]-=7
```

## Also for clarification, here are my variables:

```
playerpos=[100,100]
 enemyArray = [pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy.png"), pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy2.png"), pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy3.png"),pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy4.png")]
    rand_enemy = random.choice(enemyArray)
    bulletspeed = 180
    acc=[0,0]
    arrows=[]
    badtimer=100
    badtimer1=0
    badguys=[[800,100]]
    healthy=[[800,100]]
    healthvalue=150
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if you have many badguys on list then you have to use list for many healt values `healthvalue = [150, 150, ...]`. Or you can keep badguy and its healt  as `badguys = [ [800,100,150] ]`

Comment: @furas Thanks, that worked. I thought it would mess with the blit() if I add another value to the list.

Comment: you can always use more complex list `badguys = [ [[800,100],150] ]`  or dictionary `badguys = [ {"pos": [800,100], "health": 150} ]`.

Comment: Please don't throw random code fragments at us and rather prepare a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, run and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep healt with every badguy

```
badguys = [ 
    [800,100,150],  
    [800,200,150],  
    [800,300,150],  
]
```

or more complex

```
badguys = [ 
    [ [800,100], 150],  
    [ [800,200], 150],  
    [ [800,300], 150],  
]
```

or as dictionary

```
badguys = [ 
    {"pos": [800,100], "health": 150}, 
    {"pos": [800,200], "health": 150}, 
    {"pos": [800,300], "health": 150}, 
]
```

This way you almost use class :)

```
class BadGuy()

    def __init__(self, x, y, health):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)
        self.health = health
        self.image = rand_enemy = random.choice(enemyArray)
        #...

    def draw(self)
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# ---

    badguys = [ 
        BadGuy(800, 100, 150), 
        BadGuy(800, 200, 150), 
        BadGuy(800, 300, 150), 
    ]
```